# API: Querying TestSets associated with a particular TestCase

Tags: rally

Is it possible to find the list of TestSets associated with a particular TestCase using the WSAPI?

When you are looking at a TestCase in Rally, you can simply click on the TestSet tab, so it seems this should be possible.  However, according to the WSAPI Doc, I don't see how to do this because there is no TestSet field on a TestCase.

And, you can't seem to go the other way, since though TestSets have a TestCase field, the doc says you can't query against it.  So how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer for you, but unfortunately this is a somewhat annoying quirk of the WSAPI data model when it comes to Test Cases. As you've observed, unfortunately there's not a Test Set attribute on Test Cases.

The only way to really handle this is client side, and it's somewhat painful. You have to obtain the TestCases collection off of each TestSet, and then loop through that collection (an array of TestCase ref's) to see if there's a match with your particular TestCase of interest.

Comment: I'm inquiring with Rally's Engineering team to see if WSAPI 2.0 (currently in beta) will help alleviate some of the top-down query pain associated with Test Sets. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: Thanks...Let me know if I can assist with that beta!  Is that truly the WSAPI, or is that the SDK 2.0 that is already available?

Comment: It's WSAPI. The beta version already shows up in WSAPI docs: `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/index.jsp?version=v2.0`.

Comment: I'll let you know if there's an early-adopter beta.